# VS2019 Winforms SDK-style project, can't add a new form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

VS20019 creates a windows forms project targeting .net framework (.net 4.7.2 namely) as an "old" style project. I have converted a newly created project to SDK style with the [Project2015To2017.Migrate2019.Tool](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Project2015To2017.Migrate2019.Tool/). Converted project runs ok but VS20019 `Add/New item` dialog shows no Winforms section and no Form template.
Still VS2017 `Add/New item` dialog successfully shows Winforms section. As well as VS20019 does for the "old" style original project.

What I'm missing?
Converted project :

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Deployment" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Form1.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="Form1.Designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <Compile Update="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <None Include="Properties\Settings.settings">
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
    <Compile Update="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

It's VS2019 Community 16.7.1 on Windows7 prof x64.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a correct project file. Note `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

For WPF and Winforms:

```
  <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
```